# Read and write file with one fopen

Tags: php

With the following code I would like to read a number from file, increase it, an write back.

```
      $DATdatei = fopen("$dir$datFile", "rw+");       
      $count = (int) fgets($DATdatei, 5000);     
      $count++;
      fwrite($DATdatei, $count);
      fclose($DATdatei);
```

But on writing back the number will be appended to the old number. I will get 1, then 12, and then 1213 ...
How to avoid it.

Comment: After reading, the file pointer is at the end of the file, which is where you'll write. You'll need to move the file pointer back to the beginning…

Comment: Or open it with a `"r"` flag, read it, close it, reopen it with a `"w"` flag, write to it, so it over writes the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `fgets()`, the file pointer will remain the the end of the file.

`fwrite()` will write it's data at that pointer.

Use a [`rewind()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) call to set the file pointer to the beginning, to overwrite the content:

> rewind — Rewind the position of a file pointer

```php
<?php

      $DATdatei = fopen("$dir$datFile", "rw+");
      $count = (int) fgets($DATdatei);
      $count++;
      
      rewind($DATdatei);
      fwrite($DATdatei, $count);
      fclose($DATdatei);
```